# Shopify order count of a particular customer

Tags: shopify

I tried using {{customer.orders_count}} in my script tag to get the total number of orders placed by a cutomer. But I am getting '0' as an output everytime. Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Comment: Please post source code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure you have a logged-in customer?
2. Are you sure that customer has orders?
3. Are you rendering the value into a DOM element?
4. Are you asking for the value you rendered into that DOM element in your ScriptTag?

That is the basic checklist I would use. Answering a question with questions. The only way to go sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

try `{{ customer.orders.size }}`

Answer (score 0):

this would work in your `<script>`

```
orderCount: "{{ checkout.customer.orders_count }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting '0' as the output for {{customer.orders_count}} in a Shopify **development** store is typical when using **test charges**. In live stores, the order count accurately reflects real orders.

Take a look at this app:
Filtered content delivery based on customer order count, spending, and marketing subscriptions.
https://apps.shopify.com/dynamic-segment-sections